# Stop duplicate results in join query in Access

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, duplicates, vba

Trying to make a query that matches up back orders with requisitions so for each back order, there will be a requisition incoming to fulfill it if matching PartNo is found.

Back Orders

```
CustomerNo  PartNo  CustomerDue
---------------------------------
1099        109100  MechShop
1012        187187  EngrShop
1259        547554  MechShop
1455        109444  WeldShop
1695        505444  EngrShop
2999        187187  MechShop
```

Incoming Requisitions

```
ReqNo  Source  PartNo  DateExp
--------------------------------
AB200  Depot1  547554  10/01/2018
RB300  Depot2  187187  02/01/2018
AB500  Depot1  547554  10/01/2018
AB560  Depot3  109453  01/01/2018
QB100  Depot4  187187  04/20/2018
RB480  Depot4  109100  01/31/2018
TB100  Depot5  547554  12/20/2018
SB500  Depot4  187187  05/01/2018
```

I linked the two by Part Number however I get repeating (duplicate?) entries for each one that matches. My link shows all records on the Back Orders table and only those that match from Incoming Requisitions so if there is a blank order showing, I know I must place a requisition to fulfill it. However, I also need to show all orders that are being filled with a respective requisition. This is what I am getting:

Query Results

```
CustomerNo PartNo CustomerDue ReqNo Source PartNo DateExp
------------------------------------------------------------
1099       109100 MechShop    RB480 Depot4 109100 01/31/2018
1259       547554 MechShop    AB200 Depot2 547554 10/01/2018
1259       547554 MechShop    AB500 Depot2 547554 10/01/2018
1259       547554 MechShop    TB100 Depot5 547554 12/20/2018
1455       109444 WeldShop
1695       505444 EngrShop
1012       187187 EngrShop    RB300 Depot2 187187 02/01/2018
1012       187187 EngrShop    QB100 Depot4 187187 04/20/2018
1012       187187 EngrShop    SB500 Depot4 187187 05/01/2018
2999       187187 MechShop    RB300 Depot2 187187 02/01/2018
2999       187187 MechShop    QB100 Depot4 187187 04/20/2018
2999       187187 MechShop    SB500 Depot4 187187 05/01/2018
```

Notice how CustomerNo 1259 & 1012 & 2999 is repeated. I only want to have the query match entries once and then move on instead of showing me all the results that match again and again. How can I achieve these in Access? I was told unique values by adding unique IDs to the Back Orders table but this didn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:
Here is my ideal results.

Query Results

```
CustomerNo PartNo CustomerDue ReqNo Source PartNo DateExp
------------------------------------------------------------
1099       109100 MechShop    RB480 Depot4 109100 01/31/2018
1259       547554 MechShop    AB200 Depot2 547554 10/01/2018
1455       109444 WeldShop
1695       505444 EngrShop
1012       187187 EngrShop    RB300 Depot2 187187 02/01/2018
2999       187187 MechShop    QB100 Depot4 187187 04/20/2018
```

Order 1012 is filled by ReqNo RB300 and then the next order for the same part is filled by the next ReqNo, in this case, Order 2999 is not filled by RB300 because it is already used and instead filled by QB100.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.  Also edit your question and show your query.

Comment: Added more info and ideal results. Thank you.

Comment: You can't solve this using a plain query as you'll have to loop through your requisitions per part to determine which backorder will be filled by which requisition. You need to write some VBA code.

Comment: @Rene So a query and VBA code or just VBA code?

Comment: I'd just use VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just show the ones that are missing?

```
select bo.*
from backorders as bo
where not exists (select 1
                  from requisitions as r
                  where bo.partno = r.partno
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you. I apologize, I also need to show those orders that are currently being filled along with those empty ones that I need to place requisitions for to fulfill.